# Scala internals of var and val

Tags: scala

What are the internal implementation of var and val in Scala? interested in knowing the details of their implementations- what makes var a "var" how mutable structure is implemented vs val (more final like) structure which makes it immutable.

Comment: Are you also interrested in how the compiler generates the byte code for `lazy val` as well?

Comment: Both are backed by a private field. Val have only an accessor method. Var have both accessor and mutator methods.

Comment: @wheaties ... and how it will evolve in the next scala version (I'm talking about the plan towards usage of invokedynamic) (but I'm not an OP)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll answer by example, using [`scalac`](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/tools/scalac.html) and [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html).

First I create `Test.scala`:

```
class Test {
  val x = 1
  var y = 2
}
```

Compile it via `scalac Test.scala` to generate `Test.class`, then use `javap -p Test.class` to get

```
public class Test {
  private final int x;
  private int y;
  public int x();
  public int y();
  public void y_$eq(int);
  public Test();
}
```

So you can see that `val x` became a `private final` field on the class, and also a `public final` method to return that value.

`var y` became a non-final private field, and a getter+setter pair. The `y_$eq(int)` is the setter. In scala, that would be `def y_=(newY: Int): Unit`. Scala's syntax sugar will translate `y = someValue` into a call to `y_=(someValue)`.

Comment: Definitions can be local, too.  Also, the REPL has a `:javap` command.

Answer (score 4):

You have to distinguish declarations (in a class template) from definitions (in a block, or in a template where they declare members and also form the constructor body)

A `var` decl is specified in section 4.2 to be equivalent to a getter/setter pair.

As an implementation detail, a `val` is just a getter.

Both members have a private backing field with a slightly mangled name: it has a trailing space.

There are a couple of anomalies, such as:

```
scala> class X { final val x = 7 }  // the underlying field is not initialized
defined class X

scala> :javap -prv X
{
[snip]
  private final int x;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_FINAL
[snip]
  public $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$X();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
```

Material difference between template and block:

```
scala> class Y { def y = { var z = 0; def z_=(zz: Int): Unit = ???; z = 1; z } }

scala> class Y { var z = 0; def z_=(zz: Int): Unit = ???; z = 1 }
<console>:7: error: method z_= is defined twice
```

In the REPL, you are really making templates (because everything is wrapped in a class):

```
scala> var z = 0 ; def z_=(zz: Int): Unit = ???
<console>:7: error: method z_= is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
       var z = 0 ; def z_=(zz: Int): Unit = ???
                       ^

scala> { var z = 0 ; def z_=(zz: Int): Unit = ??? }
```